# OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic says no instance of the function template matches the argument list?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In a cpp file, my use of:

```
BoxComp->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlap);
BoxComp->OnComponentEndOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AAICharacter::OnBoxEndOverlap);
```

got the following error:

`cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)' to 'void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(UPrimitiveComponent*, AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)`

Here's what my header file with the associated function looks like. Some of the code has been omitted to try and create what I thought was a minimal reproducible example; if I omitted anything valuable based on my lack of expertise just lmk:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "Engine/DataTable.h"
#include "Subtitle.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"
#include "Components/AudioComponent.h"
#include "AICharacter.generated.h"

/**
* The purpose of this class is to create a dummy AI for testing out the code for character interactions.
*/


UCLASS()
class GV_PROJECT_API AAICharacter : public ACharacter
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public:
// Sets default values for this character's properties
AAICharacter();

private:
UFUNCTION()
void OnBoxOverlap(AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult & SweepResult);

UFUNCTION()
void OnBoxEndOverlap(AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex)

protected:

/*If the player is inside this box component he will be able to initiate a conversation with the pawn*/
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
UBoxComponent* BoxComp;
```

Is anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: As for the error message, it is fairly self-explanatory. The thing you provided as the second argument is of type `void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)` when you needed something whose type is `void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(UPrimitiveComponent*, AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)`. (Put those two types in successive lines in a text editor if you don't see the difference.)

Comment: A [mre] would trim out the parts of `AAICharacter` that are not needed to reproduce the error. How much do you need from that class beyond the declarations of `OnBoxOverlap` and `OnBoxEndOverlap`?

Comment: @JaMiT I did understand what the error was saying, but I wasn't sure of how to give the program what it wanted. I tried adding a primitive component where it was supposedly missing one, but all that did was create a whole slew of new errors.

Comment: As for the parts unnecessary to reproduce the error, I honestly have no clue. I'm *very* new to c++ with unreal engine, and I was worried that trying to trim certain things would potentially remove valuable information that could help someone solve the problem. Looking back on it though, I suppose I could have omitted the ufunctions and uproperties safely, so I'll edit those parts out.

Comment: It is common to not know which parts are necessary to reproduce an error and which are not. That's why a standard procedure is to make a copy of your code, and in the copy start stripping out stuff. If the error disappears, you've stripped out too much. When there's nothing else you can remove without also removing the error, the example is minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is fairly self-explanatory.

> `cannot convert argument 2 from 'void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)' to 'void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(UPrimitiveComponent*, AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)`

The second argument in the indicated lines (so `&AAICharacter::OnBoxOverlap` and `&AAICharacter::OnBoxEndOverlap`) have the first type listed in the message, while the function being called (`AddDynamic()`) expects the second type. Sometimes differing types is not a problem, but in this case there is no way to convert from one to the other.

The only trick I see comes after comparing the types in question. It helps to insert spaces so that things line up better.

```
 void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(                      AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)
 void (_cdecl AAICharacter::*)(UPrimitiveComponent*, AActor*,UPrimitiveComponent*,int32,bool,const FHitResult &)
```

The two member functions take fewer parameters than expected. If this is the only place those functions are used, the additional `UPrimitiveComponent*` parameter could be added directly to them. Otherwise, you might want to introduce wrapper functions that have the needed signature, ignore their first parameter, and call the method (one wrapper would call `OnBoxOverlap()`, while the other would call `OnBoxEndOverlap()`). For example:

```
UFUNCTION()
void OnBoxOverlapWrapper(UPrimitiveComponent* /*ignored*/, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult & SweepResult)
{
    OnBoxOverlap(OtherActor, OtherComp, OtherIndex, bFromSweep, SweepResult);
}
```

This comes with a caveat: do you know the significance of the parameter you are ignoring? Your code might contain a currently-unnoticed bug originating from not making use of that first parameter.

Comment: This solution worked fine with the OnBoxEndOverlap function, but the version for the OnBoxOverlap function got an error saying "missing variable name" on the following line:

`UFUNCTION()
  void OnBoxOverlapWrapper(UPrimitiveComponent* /*ignored*/, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult & SweepResult)`

Comment: @DualBall That is not enough information to figure out what is going on. Plus, it looks like a new question.

Comment: Gotcha; I'll ask my new question elsewhere. Thanks for the help!